# How can you make a Javascript Regex only match when two characters are beside each other?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to split a paragraph into sentences:

```
var sentences = /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g;
```

I would like it only to match if the punctuation (`[\.!\?]+`) has a whitespace `\s` after it. I tried `/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+\s/g`, but that did not work.

The reason why I want this is because currently if there is a word with punctuation in the middle (like `about.me`) it is splitting it there like the `.` represents the end of a sentence when it does not. Any ideas?

For example:

If I have this paragraph:

`If the problem being solved isn't as apparent or immediately useful as traffic about.me and navigation data: weather. A few apps are trying to harness the crowd to provide accurate?`

I want it to only split into

`['If the problem being solved isn't as apparent or immediately useful as traffic about.me and navigation data: weather.', 'A few apps are trying to harness the crowd to provide accurate?']`

whereas currently it splits into

`['If the problem being solved isn't as apparent or immediately useful as traffic about.', 'me and navigation data: weather.', 'A few apps are trying to harness the crowd to provide accurate?']`.

Comment: What do you mean that it "did not work?"  What happened?  Do you have some sample sentences?

Comment: @ExplosionPills just added an example. It didn't properly split the sentence - it split it at the dot in `about.me`

Comment: Ah? Well, deleted then..! :( Though it was written on the  understanding that `x(?=y)` would only match `x` if it was followed by `y`. I may have misunderstood, though.

Comment: @DavidThomas ah I think Graham did the same thing you were doing. I didn't realize you meant to use .split. I was using .match and that regex didn't do the job, but with .split it does.

Comment: Well, dammit... ;) And no worries, I've already hit my rep-cap (and, as noted originally, I wasn't able to test) so no points lost. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var str = "If the problem being solved isn't as apparent or immediately useful as traffic about.me and navigation data: weather. A few apps are trying to harness the crowd to provide accurate?";

str.match(/.+?(\.|\?)(\s|$)/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
var re = /[\.!\?]+(?=\s)/g;

var result = "If the problem being solved isn't as apparent or immediately useful as traffic about.me and navigation data: weather. A few apps are trying to harness the crowd to provide accurate?".split(re);

console.log(result.length);  // => 2
```